# VueJS conditional rendering doesn't rerender for first time

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, getter

As the title says component only shows if the getter is updated twice and more.

I have `loading` getter, it's false by default, when it's `true`, it should show loading component, but it doesn't.

It works every time after the first change, every time you change loading after the first time it shows the component.

```
<Loading v-if="loading"></Loading>

 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["errors", "loading"])
  },
```

Vuex mutations:

```
        [types.SIGN_UP_REQUEST]: (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
        },
        [types.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS]: (state) => {
            state.loggedIn = true;
            state.loading = false;
            state.errors = {};
        },
        [types.SIGN_UP_FAILURE]: (state, { errors }) => {
            state.errors = errors
            state.loading = false;
        },
```

Comment: how are you calling the mutation?

Comment: How you define getters?

Comment: `...mapActions({ "login" }`, and `this.login(data)`, getters: `...mapGetters({ "loading" })`

Comment: Stupid mistake, I was importing component dynamically so first time wasn't being imported yet.